# Python Bit Manipulation

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, serial-communication

I'm new to python and trying to wrap my head around bit manipulation, specifically using a relay board. In the code I'm working with I see:

```
class relay_data(dict):
address = {
        "1":"2",
        "2":"8",
        "3":"20",
        "4":"80",
        "5":"1",
        "6":"4",
        "7":"10",
        "8":"40",
        "all":"FF"
        }

def testBit(int_type, offset):
    mask = 1 << offset
    return(int_type & mask)

def get_relay_state( data, relay ):
    if relay == "1":
        return testBit(data, 1)
    if relay == "2":
        return testBit(data, 3)
    if relay == "3":
        return testBit(data, 5)
    if relay == "4":
        return testBit(data, 7)
    if relay == "5":
        return testBit(data, 2)
    if relay == "6":
        return testBit(data, 4)
    if relay == "7":
        return testBit(data, 6)
    if relay == "8":
        return testBit(data, 8)
```

Can someone explain how `get_relay_state()` works?

Comment: The only bit manipulation is happening in `testBit`, the rest of the code is specific to some other purpose you haven't described at all, so I'm not sure we can help you with it. The `relay_data` class isn't used at all in the functions, so it doesn't do anything at all as far as I can tell.

Comment: As a side note: You almost certainly don't want a class that inherits from dict if you don't want it to act like a dict and use the dict's internal storage in any way. (In fact, I don't think you want a class here at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple bit-arithmetic: `get_relay_state()` does shift a `1` left by `relay` positions and then mask the `data` with it.

So in common speech: it checks if the `relay`'s bit is set. But the mapping is not linear.

For example:

```
if relay == "1":
    return testBit(data, 1)
if relay == "3":
    return testBit(data, 5)
```

The first `if` checks if relay is 1 is set and returns `2` (2nd bit) if so.
The second `if` checks if relay is 3 is set and returns `20` (5th bit) if so.

The values of the array `relay_data` coincide with the return value of the function `get_relay_state()`.

The final expression `return(int_type & mask)` returns `TRUE` if the bit is set and `FALSE` if not.